# How to transform 3D text to 2D text?

Tags: text-object, 3d-manipulator

I'm going to create a typography that transforms from 3D to 2D. It begins from 3D and eventually turns into 2D at the end.
I've researched about it, but couldn't find any tutorial. What I found was only "How to make 3D typography" tutorials. What I guess is two methods below:

1. Creating text in Blender and make it 3D, and then transform it 2D using key frame.
2. Creating text in other 2D software such as Photoshop, Gimp, or Krita. After creating the image file, import it into Blender. And then create 3D text in Blender and transform it to the 2D image file.

Which one sounds right?
Is there any tutorial video for this?

Answer (score 5):

If you "just" want to animate 3d to 2d, you can ...

[image]

keyframe bevel depth and extrude and you get e.g. this:

[image]

Comment: Extrude is what makes the thickness of the text, Offset makes the letter shape shrink/fatten on the 2D plane. https://i.imgur.com/ble094L.gif You can animate only the Extrude frankly. Plus, the offset easily breaks the mesh anyway.

Comment: you are right, i meant extrude and bevel depth...‍♂️